# In firebase (javascript), how can I get data for the currently logged in user?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've spent a few days researching for the solution. I have found many answers that were quite helpful, but still I haven't been able to find a solution that fully resolved my problem. Basically all I want to do is to get **current user's** data (stored in firebase realtime database) and display them on the user's screen.

So far, I can display data for all the user. But how can I have it display data for **only the current user**? (How can I get the push key of only the **current user**?)

- I'm not an experienced programmer (less than a year). Please use a language that is easy to understand.
- I've gone through all the firebase documentation. Please don't just give me the copy of the documentation or the link to it.

[Screenshot: Firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppnG6.png)

[Screenshot: JavaScript function for retrieving current user's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtBbr.png)

[Additional JavaScript screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbGwx.png)

Comment: It's strange how you said that you **gone thorough the firebase documnetation** but haven't came up with the answer. You answer is right here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user. The code snippets that they provided does exactly what you need.

Comment: Well that's just lack of knowledge and experience. Which snippet are you talking about? I've already tried some of them, but I still can't make it work. That's why i posted this question. I need an example of how I can use those snippets with my code.

Comment: Like I said, the code snippets are at the link in my comment. Open a read a bit. You don't need to write your own JavaScript, the Firebase SDK has everything you need.

Comment: That link does not answer OP's question. They want to know how to access data stored for a specific user. The real answer is that Google does not make any assumptions about your data structure so there is no built-in way to access a user's data; most people prefer to make a `users` document and store data under user IDs in there.

Comment: The OP asked how can he get the currently logged in user data and display that data on the page. The link **does** answer how to achieve that.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking that complicated question. All I want is to display logged-in user's profile information on the user's screen. Okay, for example, I can get the current user's uid using 'Get a user's profile' snippet. But that uid does not seem to be associated with the current user's push key that was generated by firebase when I stored the data using push().

Comment: Looking at their code, they want to get the user's country. This cannot be stored in the Firebase user object and must be stored in the database itself in a custom user document. Therefore, the link is not helpful to them because it only describes how to get the three or four fields Google lets you have on the built-in user object.

Comment: Vladimir Jovanovic, thank you, and I understand that I can achieve it using those snippets from the documentation (I believe so too). Can you please give me a little idea of how I can do it? Honestly I've been literally spending whole two days to figure out how to make it work. Again, I tried those snippets, read the documentation, but still can't make it work. That's why I finally decided to ask help and stop wasting time trying to figure out on my own

Comment: Please replace all the links to images with the actual text of the code and JSON and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make it look good. For the JSON, you can get this text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User data is wherever you choose to store it--other than `name`, `email`, and a few other fields, the User object cannot actually store any other info. Therefore, you will need to decide where in the database you want to keep your extra data.

Assuming you choose to create a collection `users` with children named by `uid`, and you store the users' countries in those documents, the following will get you a specific user's data and you can use whatever fields you'd like from there:

```
let ref = database.ref('/users/' + currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    let userData = snapshot.val();
    console.log(userData.country);
}
```

Comment: So you are saying I need to change the database structure? My understanding is that uid is auto-generated by firebase authentication whenever one signs up, and the uid not stored in the tree-structure database that I created. I can put uid in my tree-structured database? And what does 'let' in your code do? Sorry, I need to study harder

Comment: No worries, we all start somewhere! You are correct that `uid` is auto-generated and is part of the [`User` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) (i.e. `firebase().auth().currentUser` or whatever). However, the user object does *not* store data other than the fields shown in the link above. Therefore, you must create an entry in the database for each user for which you wish to store extra information. You can use the uid obtained from the User object as a way of uniquely identifying these users in the database. Please let me know if you find anything unclear!

Comment: I made it work! I successfully set uid as key for each user by using ref.child(uid).set(data) instead of using ref.push(data). Then I used the code you provided, which I found a very similar snippet on firebase docs, and it perfectly worked! (I just replaced 'let' with 'var' by the way)

Comment: Awesome! And I'm sorry I completely forgot to answer your question about `let`--basically, "modern" JavaScript uses language specification ES6 (also called ES 2015), where `var` has been superseded by `let` and `const`, which are used to declare mutable (value can change) and immutable (value cannot change) variables, respectively. ES6 adds a bunch of incredibly useful features you may want to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
function showUser(){
   var usref=firebase.database().ref("countries/"+uid);
   //uid here is the unique code u gave to the specif user
   usref.once('value', function(snapshot) {snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   if((childSnapshot.key)=="country"){
     var country = childSnapshot.val();
     //use this variable here enter code here
     window.alert(country);//just for checking!!!
   }
   if((childSnapshot.key)=="age"){
     var name = childSnapshot.val();
     //use this variable here
     window.alert(name);//just for checking!!!
   }
   });
 });
}
```

I hope this code works for you.